# Can it be solved with arctan?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

### Exercise:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x+x^2}$$

The result to that exercise  according to [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%5Cfrac%7Bdx%7D%7Bx%2Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D)

$$\ln \left|x\right|-\ln \left|x+1\right|+C$$

Can it be solved this way? As i did:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{x}\right)+c$$

My solution is based on the following formula: $$\int \frac{du}{a^2+u^2}\:=\:\frac{1}{a}\arctan\left(\frac{u}{a}\right)+c$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos okay i did that :)

Comment: In the formula $a$ is supposed to be a constant. You cannot use it with $a^2=x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, differentiating your answer yields: $$\frac{1}{2x\left(x+1\right)}-\dfrac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{2x^\frac{3}{2}}$$ which obviously doesn't equal $\frac1{x+x^2}$.

Maybe you could show your workings?

Comment: my solution is based on the following formula: $\int \frac{du}{a^2+u2}\:=\:\frac{1}{a}arctan\left(\frac{u}{a}\right)+c$

Comment: But, note that in that formula, $a$ is a constant. Here, we have $x$ and $x^2$ in the denominator, both the same **variable** $x$..

Comment: okay got you...

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Use the fact that$$\frac1{x^2+x}=\frac1{x(x+1)}=\frac1x-\frac1{x+1}.$$

Comment: thanks for the nice hint i will try to solve that this way

Comment: based on your hint it results to the Symbolab solution : $$\ln \left|x\right|-\ln \left|x+1\right|+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you result is wrong.

1. it simplifies to $\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\arctan\sqrt x+C$,
2. the derivative is $-\dfrac{\arctan\sqrt x}{2x\sqrt x}+\dfrac1{2x(x+1)}$.

---

The correct solution is obtained by noticing

$$\frac1{x(x+1)}=\frac1x-\frac1{x+1}$$ which is immediate to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint***

As an exercice you can try to use the formula with $arctan$ function ....note that $x^2+x=(x^2+x+ \frac 1 4)-\frac 1 4=(x+\frac 1 2)^2+(\frac i 2)^2$

$$\int \frac{dx}{x+x^2}=\int \frac {dx}{(x+\frac 1 2)^2+(\frac i 2)^2}$$